# Effectiveness of blue light filters for preventing delayed and decreased melatonin secretion?

Tags: sleep, endocrinology, technology, melatonin

The iPhone offers a "night shift" feature. Research indicates that blue light exposure decreases melatonin secretion (e.g., Ferguson, Melton, Li, Park, & Tosini, 2008).

To what extent do built-in blue light filters on electronic devices decrease blue light emission? Is the software program, F.lux, any better?